# Incrementing a struct name for new entries - c

Tags: c, struct

So i'm trying to use i in the name of my struct entries so I can increment it everytime I make a new entry. However, it says I must use a constant value.
But obviously if I use #define i (2) for example, I wouldn't be able to increment it since it's constant.

```
struct order {
char orderName[15];
int orderQuantity;
int orderUnderTen;
int orderUnderSixteen;
int orderStudent;
int orderOverSixty;
int orderNA;
double orderTotal;
};

int i;
struct order s[i] = { "John", 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 25.00 };
```

Am I going about this in the wrong way?
Is there a better way to increment so I can store new entries?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value `i` has an unknown, potentially random value, because you have not set it yet!

Is this line trying to set the first element of the array, or the 10th element?

```
struct order s[i] = { "John", 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 25.00 };
```

With no valid value for `i`, it could be anything!

You must first decide how big you want your array to be.

```
int i = 0;
struct order s[10] = { { "John", 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 25.00 },
                       { "Mark", 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 30.00 },
                       { "Luke", 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 35.00 } };


s[3] = (struct order){ "Matt", 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 40.00 };
i = 4;
s[i] = (struct order){ "Mike", 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 45.00 };
i++;
```

Comment: Ah, i think I get it now. So i decided how big I want my array to be. Then I would increment i as you showed in the last part for new entries. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So you want an array. If you are defining everything up front in your program code, you can let it create an array with automatic size, like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
     int id;
     char name[256];
};
struct data data[] = {
    {1, "Jon"},
    {2, "Fred"},
};
const size_t data_len = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
```

Now you can add more lines to "data" and it automatically figures out how big to make the array when it compiles the code.

In a realistic program you would load these from a data file or database and you would need to use `malloc` and `realloc` to allocate and grow a dynamic array.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an assignment to an entire structure if you use a **compound literal**:

```
struct order s[i] = (struct order){ "John", 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 25.00 };
```

Comment: `i` is still undefined, and the array size still makes no sense.